# Get Values from table using parent and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below table and on a button click I want to be able to get the content from the first 3 `<td>` and put them in an array. I have figured that I will be able to use parent and children some how but I having problems getting the final result. Below the table is the code I have so far.

```
<tr>
    <td>Content A</td>
    <td>Content B</td>
    <td>Content C</td>
    <td>
        <Button id="delete">Delete</Button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Current Jquery/Javascript:

```
$('#delete').on( "click", function( event ) {
    $(event.target).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
    var unit = $(event.target).parent().children().get(0);
    alert(unit);  //returns html element 
});
```

The end output I want is an array with `["Content A","Content B","Content C"]`

Comment: here the parent is `td`, and why do you have to remove `tr`?

Comment: Why are you naming a function delete, if you simply want to get the values? Do you want to remove the columns and then get the values in an array?

Comment: @SunnyRGupta I need to amend the values in a database because the user has deleted them

Comment: @bhb Because they are deleting the row as they do not need it there anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**JS**

```
$('#delete').on("click", function (event) {
    var _this = $(event.target);
    var tds = $(_this).closest("tr").find("td:lt(3)");
    var outArray = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < tds.length; x++){
        outArray.push($(tds[x]).text());   
    }
    alert(outArray.join(","));
});
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/uYR6A/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#delete').on( "click", function( event ) {
    $(event.target).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
    var data = [];
    $(event.target).parent().siblings("td").each(function() {
        data.push($(this).html())
    });
    console.log(data);  //returns html element 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36jRF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#delete').on( "click", function( event ) {
   var obj = $(this).parent().parent();
   $(obj).each(function(){
   alert($(this).html()) ;
   });
});
```